# Where clause in mysql query on duplicate update

Tags: php, mysql

Here is my code:

```
$query=mysql_query("INSERT into projects(user_id,1P_id,2P_id,count) 
values('$userid','$P1','$P2',1),('$userid','$P2','$P1',1) 
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE count=count+1");
```

in this code i need to use where clause to not update count for same user.

Comment: `WHERE user_id !='user_id_x'` basically. Or a `NOT IN(user1,user2,user3)`

Answer (score 1):

Can you try this,

```
$query=mysql_query("INSERT into projects(user_id,1P_id,2P_id,count) 
 values('$userid','$P1','$P2',1),('$userid','$P2','$P1',1) 
 ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE  count=count+1 WHERE user_id != '$userid' ");
```

Comment: i tried this query. But the new combination of value also not inerting,i want to restrict only update for same user @Krish R

Comment: @SaravananMP: What do you mean by *want to restrict only update for same user*. You mean to say that 1. don't update if user_id value from table matches with value of variable user_id? or 2. update, only when they match.?

Comment: don't update if user_id value from table matches with value of variable user_id @Ravinder If Different user means i want update the count.

Comment: Then which is the *KEY* field you want to check for a *duplicate*?

Comment: If the key is `user_id` then, this answer solves your problem.